# PayPal module unsupported currency exchange rate is wrong

Tags: paypal, prestashop-1.6

I have built a store on PrestaShop 1.6 that works in an unsupported by PayPal currency - BGN which at the moment has an exchange rate

```
1xEUR = 1.96 BGN
```

However, when a purchase is made the PayPal module sends the ex. 16,50 BGN as 8.00 EUR which should be 8.44 EUR.

Any idea what is going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was in the currency decimal sign. The platform was set to use no digits after the decimal sign so it was flooring the sum down.

If you have this problem go to Localization->Currencies->choose you currency-> turn on Decimals. That should be made to all currencies in order to work.